# permutation among n objects

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For n items, how many permutations are there so exactly two of the items end up in their original positions? Any idea about this problem?

Comment: Maybe it could be
$$
{n \choose{2}}\times !(n-2)
$$
where $!(n-2)$ is the number of derangements of $n-2$ objects.

Comment: Pick out $2$ from the $n$ objects (to stay where they are). Then find the number of derangements for $n-2$ objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There ar $\binom n2$ ways to select 2 elements that will be at fixed positions. There are $!(n-2)=[(n-2)!/e]$ [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the remaining elements.

Thus, the answer is $$
\frac{n(n-1)}2\left[\frac{(n-2)!}e\right]
$$

Comment: how to understand e here?  also, any regular solution version?

Comment: Please read Wikipedia page about derangements. What is regular solution?

Comment: Thanks, I mean how to do it without derangements?